# Generic Repository JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to have a Generic Repository Interface that is then extended:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
interface GenericRepository<T extends GenericModel> extends CrudRepository<T, String> {
    public T findById(String id);
}
```

I get the following error if i add findById, otherwise it compliles:

> : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'alpsController'...

Comment: Could you provide full stacktrace?

Comment: You may also want to provide the code for alpsController as it's mentioned in the error. While not a question directly related to the issue, what are you trying to gain given CrudRepository is already a generic repository.

Comment: I don't have an alps controller...

Comment: Ah, it's a spring data rest component

Answer (score 0):

CrudRepository already contains the method findOne(String id) while it doesnt resolve the error it can replace the method you have added.

Comment: Yes, i will use findOne, findById should be declared as I noteced in a class that does not have a geenric type. So if I extend genericRepository it works.